# Pass a path to the "." source in a makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, config, psql

In a directory I have a config file with my db variables.

This file (`db/database.ini`) looks like this:

```
[PostgreSQL]
host=localhost
database=...
user=postgres 
password=...
```

I have another file (`db/create_stmts.sql`) where I have all my raw create table statements, and i am trying to experiment the use of a Makefile to have a command like this:

`make create-db from_file=db/create_stmts.sql`

In order not to repeat myself, I thought of `tail`ing the variables of `db/database.ini` to a file which I would then source, creating shell variables to pass to `psql` in the make file.

Here's my plan:

```
make-db:

        # from_file: path to .sql file with all create statements to create the database where to insert
        # how to run: make create-db from_file={insert path to sql file}

        file_path=$(PWD)/file.sh
        tail -n4 db/database.ini  > file.sh && . $(file_path)

        # -U: --user
        # -d: --database
        # -q: --quiet
        # -f: --file
        psql -U $(user) -d $(database) -q -f $(from_file) && rm file.sh
```

Which I run by: `make create-db from_file=db/create_stmts.sql`

Which gives me this message - from which i kindof understand that the sourcing just did not work.

```
#from_file: path to .sql file with all create statements to create the database where to insert
# how to run: make create-db from_file={insert path to sql file}    
file_path=/home/gabriele/Desktop/TIUK/companies-house/file.sh
tail -n4 db/database.ini  > file.sh && .    
# -U: --user
# -d: --database
# -q: --quiet
# -f: --file
psql -U  -d  -q -f db/schema_tables.sql && rm file.sh
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "-d"
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'create-db' failed
make: *** [create-db] Error 2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, perhaps simpler to understand:

```
make-db:
        file_path=$$PWD/file.sh; \
        tail -n4 db/database.ini  > file.sh && . $$file_path; \
        psql -U $$user -d $$database -q -f $$from_file && rm file.sh
```

Note using `;` and `\` to convince make to run all commands in a single shell, and using `$$` to escape the `$` and use shell variable references.

Comment: Approaching this way should include `set -e` as the very first statement, otherwise exit code will be of `rm file.sh` which most probably will be 0 and indicate success even if there were a bunch of errors beforehand.

Comment: It won't be the exit of `rm` if `psql` fails, because of the `&&`.  But you're right a safer way would be to use `&&` as well after the `.` command instead of `;`.  I don't recommend people rely on `set -e` so much because it has unexpected gotchas.  This example is simple enough that it would be OK but I prefer to use `&&` as command separators and not to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the text, namely

```sh
psql -U  -d  -q -f db/schema_tables.sql && rm file.sh
```

This happens because the variables `$(user)` and `$(database)` aren't set. Every line within a target is executed in a sub shell. There is now way to use `source` like you would in a regular script.

You could create a file named database.mk in which you define these variables and use `include database.mk` at the top of your makefile to include them:

**Makefile**

```
CONFILE ?= database
include $(CONFILE).mk

test:
        @echo $(user)
        @echo $(database)
```

**database.mk**

```
user     := user
database := data
```

If you want to parse the ini file you could do that as such

```
CONFILE := db/database.ini

make-db: _setup_con
        echo $(user) $(database)
        # your target

_setup_con:
        $(eval user=$(shell grep "user=" $(CONFILE) | grep -Eo "[^=]*$$"))
        $(eval database=$(shell grep "database=" $(CONFILE) | grep -Eo "[^=]*$$"))
        # and so forward
```

Comment: I think this solution is quite complex and requires a very deep understanding of GNU make, difficult functions like `eval`, and how expansion and evaluation works.  The best solution in this case IMO is simply use semicolons and backslashes to ensure that the various lines in the recipe are all invoked by the same shell, and use shell variables.

Comment: What are you, some kind of mad scientist?! :p However, I respectfully disagree to using semi colons and backslashes for anything other than simple (almost one-line) control structures. A makefile and scripts have different applications. I would argue that the maintenance of a database has its place; import a sql file, create a database, etc. Things like joining x on y to get some kind of statistic should be written in a script.

Comment: Regarding using a separate script, I have no opinions on that.  There's also a disadvantage to creating a whole passel of little scripts to do things that could be just open coded in a recipe.  But either way is fine with me.  The thing I disagree with is using things like `$(shell ...)` and `$(eval ...)` inside make recipes to set make variables in a global scope that will then be used by other rules.  It's very abstract, and advanced (requires a deep knowledge of make to understand), and side-effect filled, and non-standard.

Comment: Hi! I found the proposed approach with Makefile and database.mk very useful. I just had to add a `.PHONY= test` on top of the Makefile cuz otherwise it would just print `make: 'test' is up to date.`

Answer (score 1):

I would make it more Make-way by using feature of automatic Makefile generation. Given that a configuration file is a simple properties file, its syntax is easily parseable by Make, it's sufficient to just get the lines with variables, i.e.:

```
include database.mk

database.mk: db/database.ini
        grep -E '^\w+=\w+$$' $< > $@

.PHONY: create-db
create-db: $(from_file)
        psql -U $(user) -d $(database) -q -f $<
```

Some additional notes:

- `create-db` should be made `.PHONY` to avoid situation when nothing is done due to somebody creating (accidentally or not) a file named `create-db`,
- by making `create-db` depending on `from_file` one can get a clean and readable error from `make` that a file does not exist instead of possibly cryptic error later.